# How can I reduce amount of boilerplate code while working with TypeScript+mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Let's say I have two entities: *Vehicle* and *Tariff*. They are related as 1-to-many (vehicle can has many tariffs).

This is my basic types definition of objects, I want to work with:

```js
interface Tariff {
    id: string;         // <-- ID of entity
    createdAt: Date;    // <-- some meta data fields for sorting and etc.

    days: number;       // <-- userful info
    price: number;      // <-
}

interface Vehicle {
    id: string;          // <-- ID of entity
    createdAt: Date;     // <-- some meta data fields for sorting and etc.

    model: string;       // <-- userful info
    year?: string;       // <-
    seatsCount?: number; // <-
    tariffs: Tariff[];   // <-- array of tariffs
}
```

Looks great. No we need to create database model. First let's define mongoose schema:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const vehicleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdAt: {type: Date, required: true, default: () => new Date()},

    model: {type: String, required: true},
    year: String,
    seatsCount: Number,
});
```

Awesome. I decided no to put tariffs inside vehicle documents and they will be stored separately.

Next we need to create mongoose model. But we need to provide generic type extending `mongoose.Document` to `mongoose.model`. And this is where code duplication begins:

```js
// First we need to define TypeScript schema equalent of mongoose schema:
interface VehicleSchema {
    createdAt: Date;

    model: string;
    year?: string;
    seatsCount?: number;
}

// Then we need to defined a new type of out vehicle models:
type VehicleModel = VehicleSchema && mongoose.Document;

// And finaly we can create model:
const VehicleModel = mongoose.model<VehicleModel>("Car", carSchema);

// Look, here is a type named "VehicleModel" and a constant named "VehicleModel"
```

Now we can write functions for CRUD operations:

```js
namespace vehicle {
    export const create = async (form: VehicleCreateForm): Promise<Vehicle> => {
        const fields = toDb(form);

        // assume form is prevalidated
        let dbVehicle = new VehicleModel(form);
        dbVehicle = await model.save();

        // tariff - is the separate module, like this one,  
        // createAllFor methods retuns Tariff[]
        const tariffs = await tariff.createAllFor(dbVehicle.id, form.tariffs);

        return fromDb(dbVehicle, tariffs);
    }

    //...

    // export const update = ...
    // export const list = ...
    // export const get = ...    
    // etc..
}
```

Here we intoduce one extra type: `VehicleCreateForm`, it describes all fields needed to create vehicle:

```js
interface VehicleCreateForm {
    model: string;
    year?: string;
    seatsCount?: number;
    tariffs: TariffCreateFields[]; // <-- here is another one special type
}

interface TariffCreateFields {
    days: number;
    price: number;
}
```

Also we need to define two functions: `toDb` to prevent some fields, f.e. `tariffs` be passed to model. And `fromDb` "translates" model to `Vehicle` entity, removes or converts some fields:

```js
const u = <T>(value: T | undefined | null): (T | undefined) => value === null ? undefined : value;

const toDb = (f: VehicleCreateForm): VehicleCreateFields => ({
    model: f.model,
    year: f.year,
    seatsCount: f.seatsCount,
});

const fromDb = (m: VehicleModel, tariffs: Tariff[]): Vehicle => ({
    id: m.id,
    createdAt: m.createdAt,

    model: m.model,
    year: u(m.year),
    tariffs,
});
```

And, yaaa, we need one more extra type: `VehicleCreateFields`. Fields we are passing to model constructor.

```js
interface VehicleCreateFields {
    model: string;
    year?: string;
    seatsCount?: number;
}
```

Seems like here is done.

Also we need to define `tariff` namespace similar to `vehicle`. All types and will be duplicated too: `TariffSchema`, `TariffModel`, `TariffCreateForm`, `TariffCreateDocument`.

And this will happen for every new entity. In current case I can avoid creating `VehicleUpdateFields` type and use `VehicleCreateFields` for creating and updating. There could be also `VehicleUpdateDocument` and etc.

How can I reduce the amount of code duplications. How you deal with typescript/mongoose?

Ofcouse I can extract common fields to "common chunck" interfaces, but I event don't know how to name them.

Comment: If you're referring to the fact that some properties are duplicated, then why not create a higher order interface with the dups? because you could technically do something like `interface Tariff extends UserInfo` where `UserInfo` is an interface with everything regarding users.

Comment: I tried this. And this become to some messy hello of `VehicleCommonFields`, `VehicleModelCommonFields` and so on. Since some fields can have different types for model and for entity. F.e. I can have some field `foo` that in `Vehicle` entity has type `A`, and in model type it is serialized to `string`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228020/creating-mongoose-models-with-typescript-subdocuments/55194560#55194560
i hope this can help you